# Creating links to Tagger tags with Zoo Triggers

Tags: devdemon, zoo-triggers

I'm trying to figure out something I thought would be fairly easy and straight forward, but I'm having a difficult time trying to figure this out.

Zoo Triggers says: "Filter tags from the url support DevDeamon Tagger" - I appear to have everything in place and installed correctly.

- Zoo Triggers 1.2.2
- Tagger 3.2.1
- EE 2.7.2

I've tried a number of different things, I can get the tags to output, but I try to use the same syntax with Zoo Triggers Tags as I have with Archives and I get thrown and error:
Error

The following tag cannot be processed:
{exp:zoo_triggers:tag}
Please check that the ‘zoo_triggers’ module is installed and that ‘tag’ is an available method of the module.

Basically I'm trying to do exactly what devot-ee is doing at the bottom of the left column when looking at an add-on.

Any insight on how to do this would be invaluable. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the documentation (http://ee-zoo.com/docs/triggers/tags/index.html) you will see that there is no 'tag' tag available. Just because the Tagger add-on has really good tags available (http://www.devdemon.com/docs/tagger/tags/index.html) for printing out the tags you want.

If you want to filter these tags, just make sure you use the tag filter by pointing the URL to `http://example.com/news/tags/testtag`.

To filter on multiple tags you can do the following: `http://example.com/news/tags/testtag/anothertag/test`

Comment: Thanks Filip! Got it all figured out now. I appreciate you help.